# Unable to type in dropdown of dbutils.widgets.dropdown()

Tags: amazon-web-services, widget, aws-databricks, apache-commons-dbutils, dbutils

In the AWS databricks widgets.dropdown, I'm unable to type input in the dropdown box:

[image: Databricks dropdown]

I'm unable to find the reason of this type of behaviour.

Comment: According to [Databricks widgets | Databricks on AWS](https://docs.databricks.com/notebooks/widgets.html), a `dropdown` is "Select a value from a list of provided values." If you want to type something, you'd probably need to use `text` or `combobox`.

Comment: What `dbutils.widgets` code are you using? Please Edit your question and show us the code that is generating the widget.